# How set background color of a button - xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uibutton

How can I set the background color of a `UIButton` in Xcode?

I see the property Background and Image in the layout property but i can't set anything in this two. (I can set only image in both not colors)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Just scroll a little bit in `Attribute Inspector`, you can find `Background` property in `view` section that will allow you set the `backgroundColor` for the `UIButton`.

[image]

If you want to set `backgroundColor` of button programatically.

**Objective C :**

```
 self.yourButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

**Swift 3 and Swift 4**

```
 self.yourButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
```

**Swift 2.3 or lower**

```
 self.yourButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

Comment: @ParagKadam For that select Last option in color `other`. After that in Color popup select **RGB Sliders** from drop down and you see hex color field set the hex color there will set your color to background.

Answer (score 9):

If you are working with Objective-C then this is the code for setting button background Color.

```
YourButtonObject.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
```

[image]

And you can direct setting background color of `UIButton` from storyboard like following:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Swift 2.3

```
    btn.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 17.0/255.0, green: 119.0/255.0, blue: 151.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

In storyboard
[image]

Comment: Ah, the classic "scroll down" conundrum. Thanks Rajesh!