# How to change a button background in Storyboard

Tags: swift, xcode-storyboard, nsbutton

Most of my buttons are handled programmatically so they can be easily customized EXCEPT one.
And I haven't figured out how to personalize it's background to a custom theme color.

Comment: See if this thread has what you need https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41074243/how-set-background-color-of-a-button-xcode

Comment: This is Mac OS? You should add that tag. And you need to add a lot more detail. Show how you are creating this button, what the background currently looks like, and what you want it to look like instead.

Comment: Hint: `CALayer.backgroundColor`

Comment: Add an outlet and customize programmatically?